# Auto reload included page after changing $_GET

Tags: php, jquery

I need to reload included page in  after user clicks the specific link, which changes the tournament id.

info.php

```
  <?php  
   $tournament = $_GET['tournament'];
   $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   $sql=$conn->query("SELECT *, SUM(points) as total FROM results WHERE tournament_id = '$tournament' and user_id = '$user' ");
   $data=mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
   echo 'Logged user '. $_SESSION['name'] .', score '. $data->total . 'in tournament '. $data->tournament_name; ?>
```

in main layout I have:

```
<div id="info"> 
   <?php include "info.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="main">Select tornament:  
 <a href="competition.html?tournament=1">Tournament 1</a><br />  
 <a href="competition.html?tournament=2">Tournament 2</a><br />
</div>
```

I need to automatically refresh div where page "info.php" loads to get logged user's points from chosen tournament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot re-execute an included PHP script once the page is generated and loaded. So you have two solutions:

1. Use AJAX to request the info.php from the server and then insert the received content in the DIV using JavaScript:

   document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=ReceivedContent;
2. Use IFRAME instead of DIV and reload it when needed.

HTML:

```
<IFRAME id="info" src="info.php"></IFRAME>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("info").contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if your ever using User Input in an SQL statement, you should escape it using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or risk [injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

```
$conn->real_escape_string( $_GET['tournament'] );
```

Apart from that I'm not entirely sure what your asking, as it appears what you have already works, but you can make it more robust by not running the PHP code if a tournament is not selected.

```
<?php  
   if ( isset( $_GET['tournament'] ) ) {
      // Your code here.
   };
?>
```

You can also add a form instead of using anchors (links).

```
<form method='get' action='competition.html'>
   <input type='radio' name='tournament' value='1' checked> Tournament 1<br>
   <input type='radio' name='tournament' value='2' checked> Tournament 2<br>
   <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use from jQuery and jQuery Ajax:

First of all you should have jQuery in your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now you should send Ajax request to info.php on use click and show related data:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#main a").click(
        function(){
             var request = $(this).attr("href");
             $.ajax({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: request 
             }).done(function( msg ) {
                  $("#info").html(msg);
             });
             return false;
        }
    )
});
</script>
```

and change html to:

```
<div id="main">Select tornament:  
     <a href="info.php?tournament=1">Tournament 1</a><br />  
     <a href="info.php?tournament=2">Tournament 2</a><br />
</div>
```